# My variable is not being set when I get current user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter with dart language and I have an issue with user is already authenticated by google, but only I want get his email to filter his data.

Why inside 'setState' method is getting user and then currentUser is null again????

```
 class ListDataState extends State<ListScreen> {

  List<Data> list;
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  void _loadCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() {
        this.currentUser = user;
        print("- user authenticated: ${currentUser.email}");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser==null  )print("- Now my user is null");

     filterDataByUser()
  }

 void filterDataByUser(){
    if(currentUser==null  )print("- Now my user is still null");
     Stream<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot=_db.collection("collection").where("userEmail",isEqualTo: currentUser.email)
    // adding data to list
 }

 // ... some code listing data by authenticated user ...
 }
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (24753): - user authenticated: xxx@gmail.com
I/flutter (24753): - Now my user is null
I/flutter (24753): - Now my user is still null
```

This code works if I change this part of code:

```
.where("userEmail",isEqualTo: currentUser.email)
```

by my email:

```
.where("userEmail",isEqualTo: "xxx@gmail.com")
```

Comment: where are you calling `filterDataByUser()` from?

Comment: I call this function in initState(), I didn't show this line because I thought it was not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_loadCurrentUser()` should be async so that you wait for the function to finish executing before calling this code `if(currentUser==null  )print("- Now my user is null");`.

```dart
class ListDataState extends State<ListScreen> {

  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  Future _loadCurrentUser() async{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      currentUser = user;
      print("- user authenticated: ${currentUser.email}");
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filterDataByUser();
  }

  void filterDataByUser() async{
    await _loadCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser==null)print("- Now my user is null");
    if(currentUser==null)print("- Now my user is still null");
  }

// ... some code listing data by authenticated user ...
}
```

Comment: I will update my question with this 'async' but it does not resolve the issue

Comment: adding `async` alone wont do anything, trying running my code instead

Comment: you were rigth, 'await' instruction was needed. thank you very much